# Proving an expression is 0 over a curve

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\Gamma$ a differentiable curve over $\mathbb{R^2}$. Given $z\in\Gamma$, we define $T_z$ as the unit tangent vector at $z$. I want to prove that the expression

$$\frac{T_w}{w-z}-\frac{\overline{T_z}}{\overline{w-z}}, \hspace{0.3cm} w,z\in \Gamma,  w\neq z$$

equals $0$ when there exists a circular arc tangent to both points $w,z$.

I do not have any idea how to solve it. Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

When there exists a circular arc tangent to both points $w,z$, there exists a rotation $R$ of the complex plane of center $a$ and angle $\theta$ such that $w-a = (z-a)e^{i \theta}$ and $T_w = e^{i\theta} T_z$. Also have in mind that the modulus of $T_z,T_w$ is equal to one and that $T_z$ (respectively $T_w$) is orthogonal to $z-a$ (respectively $w-a$).

Using those relations, you'll get the desired result.